# SWT in eclipse Java JDE not working

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

When I input the following Java code into eclipse, it returns an error. I am told by the eclipse tutorials that this should work. What am I doing wrong?
[This is a picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5LCs.png).

```
import org.eclipse.swt;
public class SWTHELLOWORLD{
      public static void main(String[] args){
           Display display=new Display();
           Shell shell = new Shell(display);
           shell.setText("Hello world");
           shell.open();
           while(!shell.isDisposed()){
                if(!display.readAndDispatch())display.sleep();
           }
           display.dispose();
     }
}
```

When I run as a java application, it returns this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Display cannot be resolved to a type
    Display cannot be resolved to a type
    Shell cannot be resolved to a type
    Shell cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: I am running windows 10.

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Paste your code and error messages into your question (And format it to make it readable). To Your Problem: The class is called `String` not `Strings`. Also it looks like you are doing no imports at all.

Comment: You really need to read up on the Java basics. The error messages are very clear as well. You're missing imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not importing the Display and Shell classes.

You should add the following imports to the top of your class:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell
```

Just importing `org.eclipse.swt` will not import all the classes that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You used

`public static void main (Strings[] args)`

while the correct way of putting it would be

```
public static void main (String [] args)
```

Mind that it is String without the 's' in the end.

Comment: I did this, and I got this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Display cannot be resolved to a type
 Display cannot be resolved to a type
 Shell cannot be resolved to a type
 Shell cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Sorry. Add 
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell
 to your imports and it should work.